# c++ / SFML - Memory leak shown in valgrind report

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, sfml

I've this little code that repeatedly draws a shape using SFML. It aborts abruptly with different error messages, like `corrupted size vs. prev_size / Aborted (core dumped)`, `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer /` or `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I used valgrind to track down what looks like some memory leak, but the report is rather cryptic to me. Nevertheless, as far as I understand the thing, "**definitely lost: 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks**" is not a good omen. The most puzzling is that it does not abort when I run it through valgrind.

I'll keep on investigating, but if anyone could give me a hint, that would be great.

Best regards,

MC

`g++ -std=c++11 ./k.cpp -o ./k -Wfatal-errors  -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <random>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct point {
 double x;
 double y;
};

struct curve {
 int index;
 point centerPoint;
 double radius;
 sf::ConvexShape shape;
 sf::Text curveName;
 point curveNamePosition;
};

curve computeCurve(point centerPoint, double radius) {
 unsigned short numberOfPoints = 200;
 curve curve;
 curve.shape.setPointCount(numberOfPoints);
 curve.centerPoint.x = centerPoint.x;
 curve.centerPoint.y = centerPoint.y;
 curve.radius = radius;
 double alpha = 2 * M_PI / numberOfPoints;
 unsigned short a = 1;
 point point;

 for (unsigned short i = 0; i < numberOfPoints + 1; i++) {
   point.x = radius * (0.5 + cos(2 * a * alpha * i) / 2) * cos(alpha * i) +
             centerPoint.x;
   point.y = radius * sin(a * alpha * i) + centerPoint.y;
   curve.shape.setPoint(i, sf::Vector2f(point.x, point.y));
 };

 for (unsigned short i = 0; i < numberOfPoints - 1; i++) {
   point.x = radius * (0.5 + cos(2 * a * alpha * i) / 2) * cos(alpha * i) +
             centerPoint.x;
   point.y = -radius * sin(a * alpha * i) + centerPoint.y;
   curve.shape.setPoint(2 * numberOfPoints - i,
                        sf::Vector2f(point.x, point.y));
 };

 curve.shape.setOrigin(curve.centerPoint.x, curve.centerPoint.y);
 curve.shape.setPosition(curve.centerPoint.x, curve.centerPoint.y);
 curve.curveNamePosition.x = curve.centerPoint.x;
 curve.curveNamePosition.y = curve.centerPoint.y;
 curve.curveName.setString("Curve");
 curve.curveName.setPosition(curve.centerPoint.x, curve.centerPoint.y);

 return curve;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 const unsigned short windowWidth = 800;
 const unsigned short windowHeight = 800;

 sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), "Demo",
                         sf::Style::Default); // Default / None // Fullscreen
 string myfontFileName = "./media/Arial.ttf";
 sf::Font myFont;

 if (!myFont.loadFromFile(myfontFileName)) {
   cout << "Could not find the font " << myfontFileName << endl;
 }

 sf::Event myEvent;
 sf::Clock curveClock;
 // Initialization
 point centerPoint;
 centerPoint.x = 300;
 centerPoint.y = 300;
 double radius = 200;
 curve mt = computeCurve(centerPoint, radius);
 mt.shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
 mt.shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(40, 140, 10, 127));
 mt.shape.setOutlineThickness(1.f);
 mt.curveName.setFont(myFont);
 mt.curveName.setCharacterSize(20);
 mt.curveName.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);

 std::random_device randomDevice;
 std::mt19937 seed(randomDevice());

 while (window.isOpen()) {
   while (window.pollEvent(myEvent)) {
     if (myEvent.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed) {
       window.close();
     }
   }

   window.clear();

   if (curveClock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() > 200.0f) {
     std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> rDistribution(
         10, 300);
     double radius = rDistribution(seed);

     std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> cDistribution(
         100, 300);
     centerPoint.x = cDistribution(seed);
     centerPoint.y = cDistribution(seed);

     mt = computeCurve(centerPoint, radius);
     mt.shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
     mt.shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(40, 140, 10, 127));
     mt.shape.setOutlineThickness(1.f);
     mt.curveName.setFont(myFont);
     mt.curveName.setCharacterSize(20);
     mt.curveName.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
     curveClock.restart();
   }
   window.draw(mt.shape);
   window.draw(mt.curveName);
   window.display();
 }
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It's a fairly small code. Just systematically remove things until you find what's causing it. I don't see any dynamic allocations (except the ones SFML do internally) so seems strange that you would get memory leaks with this.

Comment: Sorry, It's already stripped to the bone. But I found the anomaly. It lays within equation of the curve itself. For a a=1 value of the parameter, the second loop compute a second time the same set of point. So each point is duplicated in the curve.shape. It's way too much for SFML, I guess.

Comment: When you post code please take care to have some proper indentation what makes the code easier for others to read and understand if. (but also for your self to find errors) and makes it easier to manage your code with tools like `git`. Most IDEs can do that for you or you can use `clang-format` or a website like [zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I'll use a coherent indentation next time.

Answer (score 1):

There was definitely an error in the way the equation was defined. Here is a corrected code if someone is interested.

Best regards,

MC

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <random>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct point {
  double x;
  double y;
};

struct curve {
  int index;
  point centerPoint;
  double radius;
  sf::ConvexShape shape;
  sf::Text name;
  point namePosition;
};

curve computeCurve(point centerPoint, double radius) {
  std::random_device randomDevice;
  std::mt19937 seed(randomDevice());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> aDistribution(1, 4);
  int a = aDistribution(seed);

  unsigned short numberOfPoints = 100 * a;
  curve curve;
  curve.shape.setPointCount(numberOfPoints);
  curve.centerPoint.x = centerPoint.x;
  curve.centerPoint.y = centerPoint.y;
  curve.radius = radius;
  double alpha = 2 * M_PI / numberOfPoints;

  point point;

  for (unsigned short i = 0; i < numberOfPoints + 1; i++) {
    point.x = radius * (0.5 + cos(2 * a * alpha * i) / 2) * cos(alpha * i) +
              centerPoint.x;
    point.y = radius * sin(a * alpha * i) + centerPoint.y;
    curve.shape.setPoint(i, sf::Vector2f(point.x, point.y));
  };

  curve.shape.setOrigin(curve.centerPoint.x, curve.centerPoint.y);
  curve.shape.setPosition(curve.centerPoint.x, curve.centerPoint.y);

  curve.namePosition.x = curve.centerPoint.x;
  curve.namePosition.y = curve.centerPoint.y;
  curve.name.setString("Curve");
  curve.name.setPosition(curve.centerPoint.x, curve.centerPoint.y);

  return curve;
}
curve computeCardioid(point centerPoint, double radius) {
  double perimeter = 8 * radius;
  int numberOfPoints = max(floor(perimeter / 3), 20.0d);
  curve curve;
  curve.shape.setPointCount(numberOfPoints);
  curve.centerPoint.x = centerPoint.x;
  curve.centerPoint.y = centerPoint.y;
  curve.radius = radius;
  double alpha = 2 * M_PI / numberOfPoints;
  point point;

  for (unsigned short i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
    point.x = 2 * radius * (1 - cos(alpha * i)) * cos(alpha * i) +
              curve.centerPoint.x;
    point.y = 2 * radius * (1 - cos(alpha * i)) * sin(alpha * i) +
              curve.centerPoint.y;
    curve.shape.setPoint(i, sf::Vector2f(point.x, point.y));
  };

  curve.shape.setOrigin(curve.centerPoint.x - 1.5 * radius,
                        curve.centerPoint.y);
  curve.shape.setPosition(curve.centerPoint.x, curve.centerPoint.y);

  curve.namePosition.x = curve.centerPoint.x;
  curve.namePosition.y = curve.centerPoint.y;
  curve.name.setString("Card");
  curve.name.setPosition(curve.centerPoint.x, curve.centerPoint.y);

  return curve;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  const unsigned short windowWidth = 800;
  const unsigned short windowHeight = 800;

  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), "Demo",
                          sf::Style::Default); // Default / None // Fullscreen
  string myfontFileName = "./media/Arial.ttf";
  sf::Font myFont;

  if (!myFont.loadFromFile(myfontFileName)) {
    cout << "Could not find the font " << myfontFileName << endl;
  }

  sf::Event myEvent;
  sf::Clock curveClock;
  // Initialization
  point centerPoint;
  centerPoint.x = 300;
  centerPoint.y = 300;
  double radius = 200;

  curve curve = computeCurve(centerPoint, radius);
  curve.shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
  curve.shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(40, 140, 10, 127));
  curve.shape.setOutlineThickness(1.f);
  curve.name.setFont(myFont);
  curve.name.setCharacterSize(20);
  curve.name.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);

  random_device randomDevice;
  mt19937 seed(randomDevice());

  while (window.isOpen()) {

    while (window.pollEvent(myEvent)) {
      if (myEvent.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed) {
        window.close();
      }
    }

    window.clear();

    if (curveClock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() > 1000.0f) {
      uniform_int_distribution<mt19937::result_type> rDistribution(10, 300);
      double radius = rDistribution(seed);

      point centerPoint;
      uniform_int_distribution<mt19937::result_type> cDistribution(100, 300);
      centerPoint.x = cDistribution(seed);
      centerPoint.y = cDistribution(seed);
      curve = computeCurve(centerPoint, radius);
      curve.shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
      curve.shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(40, 140, 10, 127));
      curve.shape.setOutlineThickness(1.f);
      curve.name.setFont(myFont);
      curve.name.setCharacterSize(20);
      curve.name.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
      curveClock.restart();
    }

    window.draw(curve.shape);
    window.draw(curve.name);
    window.display();
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Answering your own question is great. To improve the answer it would be nice if you point out which change solved your problem. Without that, a future reader that might have the same problem will need to diff both codes, and in your case that especially complicated as you changed many things (including namings, and other stuff).

Comment: The error came from the second loop when calculating the coordinates of each point of the curve. This second loop was superfluous, and was computing the whole set of points a second time. When drawing the line, I guess SFML was getting upset to get twice the same set of points for a single shape.